# How do we know that the non-satisfaction of Leggett's inequalities falsifies realism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

To refresh, Leggett's inequalities are based on two assumptions:

"
1. Macrorealism per se: 'A macroscopic object, which has available to it two or more macroscopically distinct states, is at any given time in a definite one of those states.'

2. Noninvasive measurability: 'It is possible in principle to determine which of these states the system is in without any effect on the state itself, or on the subsequent system dynamics.'
   "

-Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leggett%E2%80%93Garg_inequality)

Now obviously if 1 is false then realism is falsified, but I don't see how 2 being false would falsify realism.  It seems to me that 2 being false could be a consequence of non-locality rather than non-realism.  Please correct me!